# Single-threaded

Tags: python, c, c++

Кто может пояснить что значит строки 724, 725  их смысл о потоке [rlm_python.c](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/src/modules/rlm_python/rlm_python.c). Простым языком.

Comment: /*
* The module name should be the only globally exported symbol.
* That is, everything else should be 'static'.
*
* If the module needs to temporarily modify it's instantiation
* data, the type should be changed to RLM_TYPE_THREAD_UNSAFE.
* *** The server will then take care of ensuring that the module ***
* *** is single-threaded. ***
*/

Answer (score 1):

"Тогда сервер (видимо, которым запускается данный модуль) обеспечит, чтобы модуль запускался в однопоточном режиме" (и проблем с изменением одной переменной несколькими экземплярами не будет)

Comment: > и проблем с изменением одной переменной несколькими экземплярами не будет

Может быть, несколькими потоками, а не экземплярами? Да и вообще, это корректнее назвать обобщенным "потокобезопасность".

Comment: Да, несколькими экземплярами модуля, работающими в разных потоках. Что и называется "потокобезопасностью" :)